# Как выбрать пронумерованную строку из JSON

Tags: javascript, json

Есть файл json, в нем содержатся данные, и один массив с массивами, т.е. этот первый массив содержит строки, в которых данные.
как вывести опеределенную из этих строк, если они имеют номер?
Прямо в браузере, по умолчанию выводится последняя, а необходимо GET'ом задавать номер необходимой строки, что бы её браузер и отдавал.
Как это реализовать? Или как нужно переделать этот объект?

```
{
  "fileFormatVersion":"2",
  "guid":"99dcb1e7315ff47ca968425d83d3454f",
  "timeCreated":"1505390140", 
  "licenseType":"Pro",
  "TextScriptImporter": [{
    "line": "1", "symbols":[3,7,2,4,7,2,2,8,1,4,9,6,5,3,7],
    "line": "2", "symbols":[4,5,7,1,7,4,5,4,2,5,6,3,9,3,1],
    "line": "3", "symbols":[4,1,6,6,3,1,3,7,4,2,7,5,1,3,2],
   }],
  "userData":"",
  "assetBundleName":"",
  "assetBundleVariant":""
}
```

Comment: _Прямо в браузере, по умолчанию выводится последняя, а необходимо GET'ом задавать номер необходимой строки_ что? Каким кодом выводится последняя? Если нужно гетом, то тогда сервер должен отдавать нужные данные

Comment: Просто открывает этот json в браузере, но необходимо доставать лишь определенную строку, из этих трех

Comment: У вас массив, в котором 1 объект, в котором 3 раза повторяется ключ `line` и 3 раза повторяется ключ `symbols`, вы уверены что так и должно быть? Ключи банально друг друга перезапишут и останется только последний. Я думаю вам нужен массив с тремя разными объектами.

Comment: Хорошо, как можно переделать данный код, что бы моя идея заработала? Можно пример? Я не особо шарю именно в этой системе

Comment: Это не код, это просто `JSON`. Вы хотите делая определенный запрос к этому файлу получить определенные данные? Делайте `route`(или его еще называют `endpoint` на сервере, обрабатывайте запрос, отправляйте нужные данные. Либо посмотрите на ответ ниже. Этот ответ предполагает использование `JavaScript` для работы с этим `JSON` объектом.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Воспользуйтесь методом `JSON.parse`, он вернет объект из вашего `JSON`, с которым можно уже работать

```js
const jsonData = `{
  "fileFormatVersion":"2",
  "guid":"99dcb1e7315ff47ca968425d83d3454f",
  "timeCreated":"1505390140", 
  "licenseType":"Pro",
  "TextScriptImporter": [
    {"line": "1", "symbols":[3,7,2,4,7,2,2,8,1,4,9,6,5,3,7]},
    {"line": "2", "symbols":[4,5,7,1,7,4,5,4,2,5,6,3,9,3,1]},
    {"line": "3", "symbols":[4,1,6,6,3,1,3,7,4,2,7,5,1,3,2]}
   ],
  "userData":"",
  "assetBundleName":"",
  "assetBundleVariant":""
}`;

const data = JSON.parse(jsonData);
const result = data.TextScriptImporter[0]; // первый элемент
console.log(result)
```

Нужно заменить ваш массив с одним объектом:

```
  "TextScriptImporter": [{
    "line": "1", "symbols":[3,7,2,4,7,2,2,8,1,4,9,6,5,3,7],
    "line": "2", "symbols":[4,5,7,1,7,4,5,4,2,5,6,3,9,3,1],
    "line": "3", "symbols":[4,1,6,6,3,1,3,7,4,2,7,5,1,3,2],
   }],
```

На массив с тремя, что бы ключи не дублировались:

```
  "TextScriptImporter": [
    {"line": "1", "symbols":[3,7,2,4,7,2,2,8,1,4,9,6,5,3,7]},
    {"line": "2", "symbols":[4,5,7,1,7,4,5,4,2,5,6,3,9,3,1]},
    {"line": "3", "symbols":[4,1,6,6,3,1,3,7,4,2,7,5,1,3,2]}
   ],
```

Comment: А можно ли без JS, т.е., задавать GET запрос, который будет идти вообще с другого сервера. 
Например
    file.json?line=2
Как то так?

Comment: @Denis если _другой сервер_ поддерживает такие запросы, то да. Если нет, то это не возможно одними лишь средствами запроса

Comment: просто необходимо получать именно эту строку, сервер поддерживает, но, как правильно составить этот самый запрос?

Comment: @Denis как вы поняли, что он поддерживает это API? в документации должно быть описано как, что вообще за сервер?

Comment: не совсем API, он просто должен отсылать запрос, и получать ответ, он его получает, но получает сразу весь JSON, а необходима лишь эта самая LINE, при том ее номер будет задаваться на том самом сервере

Comment: @Denis простите, но ничего не понятно. Кто отсылает запрос? Куда отсылает запрос? почему самому не парсить ответ, доставая нужные данные

Comment: Другой сервер отсылает запрос этому JSON файлу, который находится на другом сервере. Он должен доставать от туда только эту LINE, а достает весь файл